# Openmodelica OMEdit Examples Can the user modify them

Tags: openmodelica

I am trying to modify the parameters in openmodelica version 1.9.1 beta 2 using OMEdit.
But the the OK button is deactivated and no change takes effect.
Is there a way to modify and run the example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify modelica library examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118884/how-to-modify-modelica-library-examples)

Comment: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/5346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not edit the system libraries e.g Modelica. But you can extend them and then you can change the parameters. Create a new model **M** and extend it from your example (You can do it in **Create New Modelica Class Dialog**).

Comment: This answer is insufficient and unclear.