# How to modify modelica library examples

Tags: openmodelica

I am trying to run the PumpingSystem Example in the openmodelica Fluid library using the nightly build 1.9.1+dev (r21018). Unfortunately the simulation crashes saying it failed to solve NLS at initialization.
I tried to modify the model either by creating a new one extending it (which only permits the modification of the parameters but not the structure, I understand that this is probably what extension means) or by copying the text view of the model to a new file, but then OMEdit crashes.
Will you please advise how I can create a copy that I can modify?

Thank you.

PS: I am running this on Linux, the Windows version seems to translate all libraries,creates an infinite amount of translation errors "expected package to have within ; but got ..." and then terminates with a translation error "C:/OpenModelica1.9.1Nightly/lib/omlibrary/Modelica 3.2.1/Blocks/Continuous/Internal/Filter/Utilities/normalizationFactor.mo:14:3-42:27] Error: An element with name normalizationResidue is already declared in this scope."

Comment: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/5346

Answer (score 1):

You can not modify the system libraries. You can only extend them.

Creating a copy of the model is currently not supported. You can follow this ticket https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/2190

If you just copy paste the text, as you already did, you need to manually update the relative paths used in the model.

Comment: Could someone explain how to find and replace all relative paths? I try to copy a fluid example and fail to run it in a separate folder.

Comment: Supposedly copying was added, but I can't find instructions good enough to allow me to copy and edit any of the examples. Green checkmark should be removed from this answer in hopes that someone will write a more complete, up to date, answer.